# Mean of given Arithmetic function

Tags: statistics, arithmetic-functions

> Find the mean of $a, a+d, a+2d, a+3d,\dots,a+nd$

I have no idea what to do in this question but i have tried the following:
$$mean\ \bar{x}= \frac{(a)+(a+d)+(a+2d)+(a+3d)+\cdots+(a+nd)}{n+1} $$

This is obvious step we do while dealing with mean.Now i don't know what do but i think we can take $a$ common and can do something ?

Comment: Yes, one step involves computing, as you rightly notice, $\sum_{i=0}^n(a+id)$, which equals $\sum_{i=0}^n a+d\sum_{i=0}^n i = (n+1)a+d\sum_{i=0}^n i$. Do you know what $\sum_{i=0}^n i$ is?

Comment: Note that as an alternative you can pair $a, a+nd$; $a+d, a+(n-1)d$ etc - each pair has sum $2a+nd$, and there may be one item left over with value $a+\frac n2d$. This makes it easy to compute the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are n+1 times a  and take d common from left expression and you get 0+1+2+...+n-1+n whose sum is given by sum of arithmetic progression n(n+1)/2
therefore you can write numerator a(n+1) + d(n)(n+1)/2 
so your mean equals a+dn/2

Comment: we can also get this by using formula $$\frac{1^{st}term+n^{th}term}{2}$$ I also got proof for this formula

Comment: that's cool but I think your question was not this formula .

Comment: @DSinghiv yes i also know that but i was just informing that i have also got the formula

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234304/sum-of-the-sum-of-the-sum-of-the-first-n-natural-numbers @Freddy If you could go here you would get better insight in these formula

Answer (score 0):

Now distribute to make the numerator $xa+yd$.  How many copies of $a$ do you have?  What is the total of the coefficients of $d$?